# Reference manual from XDC documentation files?

Tags: c++, documentation, linq-to-xml

I'm creating a `C++` library for which I also need to make a reference manual. I used visual studio's documentation tool `XDCMake` to create [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) files that then [intellisense](/questions/tagged/intellisense) can use.

Is there a way to create a `javadoc` like, web or text, out of these files?

**Edit:**

The output looks something like this:

```
<doc>
    <assembly> "ARpp" </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:ARpp.RegionDetecter">
            <summary>
                This class extracts information about dark areas in an image which can then be processed by other modules.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:ARpp.RegionDetecter.#ctor">
            <summary>
                Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:ARpp.RegionDetecter"/>class.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <!--More members...-->
    </members>
</doc>
```

Any link, tutorial help will be appreciated.

Comment: To convert an XML file to anything else, look into XSLT. Converting your input to HTML output, for example, is very straightforward. (After searching) There seems to be no sample output anywhere on the 'web, so I cannot give any hints. Maybe you can post a sample somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) or [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/).